# Electrum console commands?

Tags: wallet, address, electrum

I need 2 commands for electrum

To create X amount of addresses
to export those addresses to word or just be able to copy them

Answer (score 1):

```
x=10

for thing in range(0,x): wallet.create_new_address()

listaddresses(True,False,False,False,True)
```

A guide about console commands is [here](https://bitzuma.com/posts/an-introduction-to-the-electrum-python-console/). Thanks to @RichApodaca for pointing that out.

Another resource is the code itself. For example you can see the function declaration for listaddresses [here](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/3.1.3/lib/commands.py#L491) which tells you what all those boolean args are for. In the above case it only outputs unused addresses in the external (receive) chain.

Comment: Can you add some explanation/links to official documentation? The code alone, while possibly correct, is not a helpful answer

Comment: @RaghavSood This page talks about how to use the console, and documents built-in functions: https://bitzuma.com/posts/an-introduction-to-the-electrum-python-console/ You can enter the code into the console.